# is it feasible to have a reference in a namespace?

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces

So this is what I have:

```
//graphics.hpp
#include guard

extern camera_c default_camera;

namespace graphics {
    camera_c &camera = default_camera;
};

#endif


//graphics.cpp

camera_c default_camera(ctor stuff);
```

---

```
//main.cpp

#include <graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    do stuff with graphics::camera;
}
```

and this gives me

```
main.o: multiple definition of graphics::camera
graphics.o: first defined here
```

I've also tried doing

```
camera_c &&camera = camera_c(ctor stuff);
```

And that gives me the same error, but from `main.cpp` and `graphics.cpp`

### So my question is

Is there some feasible way to have a reference to a class in that namespace? Or should I just use a pointer? Ideally it should be a reference, but that might not be possible.

Comment: Pointers wouldn't work either...

Comment: You've already externed `default_camera`, can't you just use that instead of `graphics::camera`?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain pointers would be able to be null, which would let me assign it a value later on, although I would have to change how it is written

Comment: @Praetorian I'm going to be switching between cameras, which is why references are used

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you'll still get multiple definition errors.

Comment: You can't change where a reference _points_.

Comment: @PatrickPowns References cannot be re-seated, so I don't see how using a reference will allow you to switch cameras. If that's your intent, you'll need to use a pointer. Use the code in DrewDormann's answer, and replace reference with pointer.

Comment: @allabove had a realisation here, thanks to Drew's answer, thanks for the help

Comment: BTW, drop the semicolon after namespaces. It only belongs after type definitions (class etc) because there you can directly create instances, too ("class foo{}f;").

Comment: @doomster you can tell I've made a total of 1 namespace(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the error.

The error is telling you that main.cpp and graphics.cpp both included graphics.hpp, which violates the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Make that variable `extern` as well:

```
namespace graphics {
    extern camera_c &camera;
};
```

And define it in **one source file only**.

```
namespace graphics {
    camera_c &camera = default_camera;
};
```

Comment: I have an include guard in graphics.hpp, just wanted to be concise, I'll edit that in now

Comment: @PatrickPowns an include guard alone will not help you.  Include guards will prevent one compilation unit from defining it twice.  But in C++ you must prevent prevent multiple definitions even across compilation units.

Comment: \*epiphany\* okay I get it now, I put that in and it compiles fine now, thanks for the help

Comment: wow, also I've been doing references wrong for years. never would have thought, they always worked.

Answer (score 2):

What about...

```
// graphics.hpp
namespace graphics {
    extern camera_c camera;
}

// graphics.cpp
#include <graphics.hpp>

namespace graphics {
    camera_c camera(...);
}
```

I must add that globally defined variables is bad style; unless you are dealing with legacy APIs, they cause more problems than it's worth!